# Getting contact list, profile pictures and emails from Google APIs

Tags: node.js, email, oauth, gmail, gmail-api

There are a few questions on individual components of "Sign in with Google" floating around, but I can't find any that refer to the current API (as of July 2015).

I have a "Log In with Gmail" option in my webapp, and I'd like to retrieve:

- All emails that I've ever sent and received (if possible)
- A list of all my contacts
- A list of all my contacts' profile pictures (and any other info that may be possible, like location, gender, age etc)

Right now, in my oAuth login I use the following scope:

```
['profile', 'email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds']
```

Then once I have my oAuth token, I make the following API call:

```
 https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=10000&alt=json&oauth_token={{token}}
```

This give me a list of contact emails and associated names, but no pictures (at least that I can find) and no other info about contacts.

I'd also like to be able to download all of the user's sent/received emails, I understand that I have to do this via IMAP but I can only find NodeJS implementations that require a username and passwords. Is it possible to do using an oAuth token?

Ideally I'd like to do this all with the one oAuth call, as I'm building an email analysis tool.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail provides an [HTTP API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) you can use to access all of a user's sent and received emails.

The Contacts API is basically only information the user has manually entered for the contact. Most users aren't going to be entering age and gender and contacts will only have locations if the user treats it like a traditional address book.

If you want to get something more like a social profile you might want to check out the [Google+ people.list API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list). You will have to find a way to correlate between contacts and Google+ profiles but Google+ profiles are more likely to have photos demographics data.